# Can't create a draft using Graph, but direct sending mail works fine

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Recently Microsoft [announced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=csharp) that it is possible to send emails with attachments larger than 4MB.

With smaller attachments, we were able to do everything in a single request.
Now we must create a draft, upload attachments and then send the file.

I have a working code that sends mail in a single request:

```
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithTenantId(tenant)
    .Build();

var authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

var email = new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
      Content = i + " Works fine! " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
      ContentType = BodyType.Html,
    },
    Subject = "Test" + (j == 0 ? "" : " " + j),
    ToRecipients = recipientList,
    Attachments = att
};

await graphClient
    .Users["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .SendMail(email, true)
    .Request()
    .WithMaxRetry(5)
    .PostAsync();
```

the above code works fine, but when I change the last line to:

```
Message draft = await graphClient
    .Users["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .MailFolders
    .Drafts
    .Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(mail);
```

or to:

```
Message draft = await graphClient
    .Users["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(mail);
```

I get an `ErrorAccessDenied` error:

> Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Why would sending email in a single request work but creating a draft fail? Do I need any special permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify which permission scopes you've selected, but this is most likely the issue.

The simplified `/sendMail` requires the `Mail.Send` permission. This is a fairly lightweight scope intended to provide an application a mechanism for sending emails without requiring access to the mailbox itself.

When creating a draft message, however, you need `Mail.ReadWrite`. This is because, unlike `/sendMail`, you need the ability to create, updated, and *then* send the message.

These are the steps and permissions required:

1. `POST /me/messages` to create the Draft Message (`Mail.ReadWrite`).
2. `PATCH /me/messages/{id}` to add/change content of the Draft (`Mail.ReadWrite`)
3. `POST /me/messages/{id}/attachments` to add an Attachment to the Draft (`Mail.ReadWrite`).
4. `POST /me/messages/{id}/send` to send the message (`Mail.Send`).

So for the scenario you're looking at, you'll want the following scopes:

- `User.Read` (req. to authenticate)
- `Mail.ReadWrite` (req. to build the draft)
- `Mail.Send` (req. to send the message)

Comment: I was missing the `Mail.ReadWrite` permissions. Thank you for help!